# Debugging network discovery using UDP broadcasting between PC and iPhone

Tags: python, swift, sockets, networking, udp

Here's the setup. I'm trying to send information from a PC to a mobile device. Currently, that setup is being executed between a Mac and an iPhone.

I'm using Python to send a UDP broadcast, so that the mobile device can detect that the PC is connected to the same network and available to send data.

Here's the Python code used on the PC:

```
import socket
import os
from time import sleep

IP = os.popen('ifconfig en0 | grep "inet\ addr" | cut -d: -f2 | cut -d" " -f1').read()
PORT = 4801
KEY = "IDKEY"

# Create socket.
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
# Bind socket.
sock.bind(('', 0))
# Configure socket.
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)

# Server Loop.
while True:
    data = KEY+IP
    sock.sendto(data.encode(), ('<broadcast>', PORT))
    print("Sent broadcast")
    sleep(5)
```

Here's the Swift code used on the mobile device (I'm using the [SwiftSocket library](https://github.com/swiftsocket/SwiftSocket)):

```
let server = UDPServer(address: "", port: 4801)
var connected = false
repeat {
    let data = self.server.recv(1024)            
    if let key = String(data: Data(bytes: data.0!), encoding: .utf8) {
        if (key == self.keyTextField.text) {
            print("Auth complete")
            connected = true
        } else {
            print("Wrong key")
        }
    }
    print(data)
} while connected == false
```

When on the Simulator, this worked just fine. However, standalone, when they're both connected to the same WiFi station, this isn't working at all. The mobile device is stuck in the infinite loop as it never receives any data.

I have to admit, I'm really new to this kind of networking, so **there's a high chance that my approach here is fundamentally incorrect**. I'd like to know what's wrong here and perhaps, **what a better approach to achieving this would be**.

Ideally, the chain of execution is as follows:

1. PC broadcasts across network that it is active.
2. Mobile device connects to network and checks the device broadcast message and see's if that's the correct one.
3. Mobile device obtains IP.
4. Communication begins over TCP, now that IP of both is known.

Comment: What do you mean "isn't working at all"? What does it do?

Comment: The mobile device never connects. There's no printout of the debug statements ("Auth complete"/"Wrong key").

Comment: Maybe you need to add some entitlements to allow it to open the port. See this answer perhaps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41396679/499581

Comment: That could be it, however, it's disheartening that it can't be submitted on the App Store.

Comment: Well, some of that information is in regards to other types of sockets; It wouldn't hurt to try, and I know they do allow some things - elevating privileges is the main thing they don't allow...

Comment: So, conceptually, what I'm trying to do here isn't incorrect right ? This is the best way of getting the IP address of the PC to the mobile ?

Comment: Usually there's more than one way of accomplishing something (hopefully), whether or not it's the "right" or "correct" way really depends on how well it actually does the job. Some folks subscribe to one thing or another and sometimes that's good, however, for certain things it's nice to be able to think outside the box — which I think is fine for the early stages of something such as what you're trying. That's really how you learn what the best way is in my opinion...

Comment: Service discovery is the domain of Bonjour.  For a lot more information on using it see https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/Discovering,Browsing,AndAdvertisingNetworkServices/Discovering,Browsing,AndAdvertisingNetworkServices.html

Comment: @DavidBerry While that is nice, I'm looking for a cross platform solution.

Comment: Bonjour is a cross platform solution.

Comment: @DavidBerry they broke it in Android O

Comment: This article certainly implies that it's natively supported.  https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd.html  Note that DNS-SD is the standards name for Bonjour.